# Convert column of lists to integer

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, bert-language-model

Trying to convert after encoding to integers but they are objects so i first turn them into strings

train_df["labels"] = train_df["labels"].astype(str).astype(int)

I am getting this error

invalid literal for int() with base 10: '[0, 1, 0, 0]

An example of a row from the dataset is

```
text                        labels
[word1,word2,word3,word4]    [1,0,1,0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because after `train_df["labels"].astype(str)`, this Series became a Series of lists, so you can't convert a list into `type int`.

If each element in `train_df["labels"]` is of type `list`, you can do:

```
train_df["labels"].apply(lambda x: [int(el) for el in x])
```

If it's of type `str`, you can do:

```
train_df["labels"].apply(lambda x: [int(el) for el in x.strip("[]").split(",")])
```

You presumably you want to train some model but you can't use pd.Series of lists to do it. You'll need to convert this into a DataFrame. I can't say how to do that without looking at more than 1 line of data.

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, your problem arises from that numbers represented as strings may be floats.  If that is the problem, then the below should solve it:

```
train_df["labels"] = train_df["labels"].astype(str).astype(float).astype(int)
```

(In Python you can't convert string representation of float numbers into `int` type.)

From the error, I suspect that your string actually includes brackets and commas (which is not crystal clear from the question). If that's the case you need to tell Python how to deal with them. For example, if train_df["labels"] is equal to "[1,0,1,0]" then you can use below:

```
train_df_labels = [int(label) for label in train_df["labels"][1:-1].split(',').strip()]

#first getting rid of the brackets in the string, 
#then splitting the string at commas and getting rid of the spaces,
#finally, converting values to int type one by one and making a list out of them
```

Comment: Turning into float produced error ValueError: could not convert string to float: '[0, 1, 0, 0]'

Comment: It seems that your string includes even the brackets and commas, is that so? If yes, then of course Python cannot figure all that out on its own. You should do something like (I added it to my answer as well): train_df_labels = [int(label) for label in train_df["labels"][1:-1].split(',')]